# Cypher syntax clarification. Multiple MATCH clauses vs using a comma

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Just after a clarification on Cypher syntax. Are the following two statements equivalent?

Using `MATCH` keyword twice:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)
MATCH (b)<--(c)
RETURN a,b,c
```

...vs using a comma:

```
MATCH (a)-->(b),
      (b)<--(c)
RETURN a,b,c
```

I couldn't find any clarification in the documentation and didn't want to make any assumptions based off the simple testing that I'd done (which seems to indicate that they do in fact perform identically).

Comment: It looks like.  The only difference in the profile is that the filter is `NOT(anon[10] == anon[21])` rather than `NOT(r == r2)` which is interesting to note